# How to print group header in every page even if no data in the details band?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a group header band, details band and group footer band.

In the first page, the group header is printed and the first page is occupied with the data in the details band(the data in the details band is exactly printed until the end of the first page) so the group footer is printed on the second page without any data/details.

My problem is that I want to print the group header on the second page too. Only the group footer is printed on the second page.

I tried checking the "Reprint Header On Each Page" but it is not working.